# I am trying to finding the files and to print ONLY size of those files

Tags: awk, find

I am trying to finding the files and to print the size of that files

```
# find . -name "*.req" -size +1000c -mtime +1 -exec 'awk "{print $5}" "{}"' \;
```

OUTPUT:

```
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696092.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696113.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696114.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696099.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696096.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696116.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696100.req": No such file or directory
find: awk "{print $5}" "./l16696117.req": No such file or directory
```

But above files exist in that location.

```
# ls -lrt l16696092.req
-rw-r----- 1 applgrnt dba 1595 Sep  5 10:35 l16696092.req
```

Answer (score 5):

Others showed how to get the file sizes, here's the cause of your strange error:

Because of the single quotes, this part

```
find ... -exec 'awk "{print $5}" "{}"' \;
```

gives `find` three parameters, `-exec`, `;` and the middle one that contains `awk "{print $5}" "{}"`. The `{}` is replaced with the current file name, say `./l16696092.req`, resulting in `awk "{print $5}" "./l16696092.req"`. Since that was the first parameter to the `-exec`, it's taken as the name of the command to run *spaces, quotes and all*. Hence the errors.

`find -exec` works better without the outer level of quotes:

```
find ... -exec awk '{print $5}' {} \;
```

But this, of course will run `awk` to read the (contents of the) files found by `find`, not get their sizes. (We still need to quote the `$` in `$5` with single-quotes or a backslash, so that the shell doesn't try to expand it.)

Comment: Don't quote `{}` in `find` commands.

Comment: Yeah, there's no need to quote the braces (unless one is running `fish`), but it shouldn't matter, `find` won't see them.

Comment: …at which point you surely need `"{print \$5}"`, yes?

Comment: @wchargin, agh, definitely. (I write single-quotes around awk commands by habit, and wasn't looking here, since that wasn't the main point.)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find(1)`:

```
find . -name '*.req' -type f -size +1000c -mtime +1 -printf "%s\n"
```

With BSD `find(1)` and BSD `stat(1)`:

```
find . -name '*.req' -type f -size +1000c -mtime +1 -exec stat -f %z {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

use `find`'s capability to print instead:

```
 $ find . -name "*.req" -size +1000c -mtime +1 -printf "%s\n"
```

see `man find` for a complete list of format specifiers

Comment: This assumes GNU `find(1)`.  BSD find doesn't have `-printf`.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
zstat -N +size -- **/*(D.L+1000m+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
find . -name "*.req" -size +1000c -mtime +1 -exec stat -c %s "{}" \;
```

or use find `-ls`

```
find . -name "*.req" -size +1000c -mtime +1 -ls | awk ' ... '
```

(i left awk code open, since you now how to make it work, you'll have to figure out which filed is size)

Comment: The first command assumes Linux syntax for `stat(1)`.